# Asking reference to the shared_ptr for underlying element_type

Tags: c++

I have very wild type and a shared_ptr pointing to it. I initialize this shared ptr to nullptr. Then I would like to construct respective object and provide the wild type as a parameter of make_shared. I would like to ask pointer to that type.

```
std::shared_ptr<cl::make_kernel<cl::Buffer&,
                                    cl_double16&,
                                    cl_double3&,
                                    cl_double3&,
                                    cl_int3&,
                                    cl_double3&,
                                    cl_double3&,
                                    cl_int2&,
                                    float&>>
        pointer = nullptr;
auto ptr = pointer;
ptr = std::make_shared<decltype(ptr)>::element_type>();
```

Unfortunately the previous code do not change value of pointer itself. So I would like to push the abstraction one level higher to have

```
auto& ptr = pointer;
ptr = std::make_shared<decltype(ptr)::element_type>();//Fails
ptr = std::make_shared<std::remove_reference<decltype(ptr)>::element_type>();//Fails
ptr = std::make_shared<std::remove_reference<decltype(*ptr)>::type>;//Works but I doubt if this provides correct type when pointer==nullptr
```

Is there a way how to ask reference to the shared pointer for the element type of the shared pointer?

You have convinced me that using std::remove_reference<decltype(*ptr)::type> is OK at it is evaluated compile time not run time. So there is still, just an academic question if there is a way how to ask that reference to the pointer directly https://godbolt.org/z/KT9oEM

*To explain why I am having this question. Imagine `pointer` is a class member and I would like to initialize it in a method without typing its element_type while typing the name `pointer` at most once.*

Comment: `decltype(*ptr)` is evaluated at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: `std::make_shared<decltype(a)::element_type>();` should work, what fails exactly?

Comment: See https://godbolt.org/z/KT9oEM where I put the errors I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decltype(ptr)` will be the type of the `shared_ptr` itself, not its element type.  You are correct to use `decltype()` on the *dereferenced* type of the `shared_ptr`.  That will be evaluated at *compile-time*, not at *runtime*, so the `nullptr` is not an issue at all:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<...> pointer = nullptr;
auto ptr = std::make_shared<std::remove_reference<decltype(*pointer)>::type>();
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/oRKM45)

**UPDATE:** in your new example:

```cpp
auto& ptr = pointer;
ptr = std::make_shared<std::remove_reference<decltype(ptr)>::element_type>();
```

`std::remove_reference` itself does not have an `element_type` member. The type you are removing `&` from (the `shared_ptr<...>` from `shared_ptr<...>&`) is the type that has the `element_type` member. You need to add `::type` after `remove_reference<... >` to access that resolved type, eg:

```cpp
std::remove_reference<decltype(ptr)>::type::element_type
```

Or, in C++14 and later, you can use `std::remove_reference_t` instead:

```cpp
std::remove_reference_t<decltype(ptr)>::element_type
```

Comment: Thank you! In practice there is a way how to do it without any doubts. But I am still curious why I am getting error: 'element_type' is not a member of 'std::remove_reference<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int> >&>' and if its possible to fix it without * operator, see https://godbolt.org/z/KT9oEM

Comment: Thank you, it fully answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a pointer to a *new* "crazy" object - not to the existing one. But you have used decltype to get a pointer of the same type. I.e. you now have 2 pointers and 2 objects.

You could do something like:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<std::remove_pointer/reference<decltype(...whatever...)>::type> new_pointer(old_pointer);
```

This pseudo code uses decltype to create the shared_ptr type, but then just assigns this to the existing object.

Another option you might want to try is an alias for your "crazy" type! - something like:

```cpp
using crazy_type = cl::make_kernel<cl::Buffer&,
                                    cl_double16&,
                                    cl_double3&,
                                    cl_double3&,
                                    cl_int3&,
                                    cl_double3&,
                                    cl_double3&,
                                    cl_int2&,
                                    float&>;

auto item = make_shared<crazy_type>();
```

I can't create an example of your exact code because I don't have all the classes - but here is a dumbed down example: https://godbolt.org/z/MKo5dj

Comment: I have explained what I am trying to achieve in the last paragraph of the question in italics. See also https://godbolt.org/z/KT9oEM